# Pop up Model does not pop up, becomes black screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax, bootstrap-modal

Here is my script for getting id of selected item

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#apply", function () {

                var url = window.location.pathname;
                var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("Apply", "Event")',
                        data: 'id=' + id,
                        success: function (msg) {

                            $('#test_modal').modal('show');
                            //setTimeout(function () {// wait for 5 secs(2)
                            //    location.reload(); // then reload the page.(3)
                            //}, 1000);
                        }
                    });


            });
        });
```

here is the modal div;

```
<div class="modal fade" id="test_modal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a> <h3>Modal Header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body"> <p>Test Alert</p> </div> <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
```

it doesnt come as pop up it comes with black screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="test_modal" style="display:none">
```

Add the style to the modal

```
$.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("Apply", "Event")',
                data: 'id=' + id,
                success: function (msg) {
                    $('#test_modal').modal('show');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the `modal` div does not have the required containing elements. The div with the `.modal-header` class should be surrounded by a div with `.model-content` and another with `.model-dialog`

A simple fix:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="test_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a> <h3>Modal Header</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Test Alert</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: still same it didnt fix

Comment: I fixed by changing the div

Comment: <div class="modal fade" id="test_modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog custom-class">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-header-text">Text</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                This is some text.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                This is some text.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: Could you add your solution as an answer so it would help the next person that has the same problem?